# Is destructive interference creation of negative entropy?

Tags: waves, entropy, interference

In the slit experiment , you find dark fringes ,since wave energy potentials are canceled, can you say that it is in one way the creation of 'nothingness'?Similar to heating due constructive interference, does cooling (reduction of entropy) happens due to destructive interference?

Comment: You can say that interference caused the absence of light at a given point. "Creating nothingness" is not a good way of describing it, though, and much less "negative entropy".

Comment: does it create cooling effects  contrary to the heating due to constructive interference?

Comment: If you had only one slit open and the light hitting the screen was partially converted to heat, then once the second slit is open, the dark fringes will become cooler and the bright ones warmer. Total energy is conserved though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"not shining light on something" is not the creation of negative entropy. It does mean that that point on the screen is receiving less energy - but it will still receive blackbody radiation from every other component in the system that is in direct line of sight. As such, the point on the screen and the rest of the system will still be striving to reach thermal equilibrium - there will be more radiation transfer from the hot to the cold than vice versa.

You can think of the light source as a "very hot" element (in the case of a laser, a hot element with a highly non-uniform emissivity). The addition of some slits makes it so that the light will preferentially reach some areas of the screen (which will heat more quickly) and less others (which will therefore behave as in the first paragraph).

Comment: Thanks, but less energy at some spots mean the interference pattern is the energy distribution of light while its a  wave ?

Comment: @Quantumkiller yes you could say that. More properly I think of it as the probability of finding a photon at a particular point in space.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your title question: not at all, indeed in many ways the opposite.

The fact that dark fringes can arise betokens a pure light state and *lack* of, or zero entropy.

Mixed light states, *i.e.* ones which are classical mixtures of pure quantum states, almost always give rise to interference patterns which have poorer fringe visibility than pure ones. That is, the contrast between light and dark regions is less pronounced. The reason for this poorer contrast is that the interference patterns arising between the different pure states in a classical mixture don't tend to align (*i.e.* their light and dark regions don't tend to be in the same places). Quantitative expressions for fringe visibility in many situations commonly have multipliers like $\exp(-\alpha\,S)$, where $S=\mathrm{Tr}(\rho\,\log\rho)$ is the von Neumann entropy of the light state and $\rho$ its density matrix.